# Use RetryPolicy with spring-data-cassandra version 3.2.8

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am new to spring-data-cassandra working on a simple project that has CRUD operations.
But facing problems while setting RetryPolicy.

I have used CassandraRepository for Person table which contains below entities

1. Name -> string
2. id -> uuid

This is my PersonRepository class

```
public interface ActionRepository extends  CassandraRepository<Person, Serializable> {

  @AllowFiltering
  Optional<Person> findByNameAndId(String Name, UUID id);

  @AllowFiltering
  Optional<Person> deleteById(UUID id);
}
```

My cassandra configuration looks like this:

```
@Bean
  @Override
  public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
    CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession = super.cassandraSession();//super session should be called only once
    cassandraSession.setUsername(userName);
    cassandraSession.setPassword(password);
    cassandraSession.setContactPoints(cassandraHost);
    cassandraSession.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
    cassandraSession.setPort(cassandraPort);
    cassandraSession.setLocalDatacenter(localDataCenter);
    return cassandraSession;
  }
```

In the code above I'm unable to set cluster configuration hence I am unable to set retry policy.

My custom retry policy looks like this:

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.ConsistencyLevel;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.retry.RetryDecision;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.retry.RetryPolicy;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.retry.RetryVerdict;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.CoordinatorException;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.WriteType;
public class CassandraRetryPolicy implements RetryPolicy {

  private int retryCount;
  private ConsistencyLevel readRetryConsistency;
  private ConsistencyLevel writeRetryConsistency;

  //Overriden Retry functions
  .
  .
  . 
  .


}
```

I tried overriding a default profile for retry policy in my CassandraConfiguration class
But not luck

P.S. cassandraRetryPolicy is my customRetryPolicy object of CassandraRetryPolicy class.

```
@Bean
  public SessionBuilderConfigurer sessionBuilderConfigurer() {
    return (sessionBuilder) -> {
      sessionBuilder.build().
              getContext().getRetryPolicies().put("default",cassandraRetryPolicy);
      return sessionBuilder;
    };
  }
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks